# Microsoft SSO working correctly in teams tab but I am getting error in task module

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

> I am getting this error
> ExtensionTabService: getAuthTokenForApp: Failed with error - Definition not found

Comment: Could you please give us more information so that we can reproduce your problem.

Comment: Have you tried to add ["inTeamsSSO=True"](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/msteams-docs/issues/1244#issuecomment-581793787) at the end of your URL?

Comment: There isn't anything mentioned about isTeamsSSO in the doc. Can you please provide some example or elaborate it ?

Comment: @AYUSHARYA Could you please share repro steps?

Comment: I am trying to open a task module via deep link URL and I am getting this error. The same is working nicely in tabs and messaging extension so I think there are no such configuration issues.

Comment: @AyushArya Do you still need help on this issue? Please share the document or steps about how to repro your issue.

Comment: The same issue is raised by other users as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63485928/teams-task-module-sso-issue.

Comment: For Repro, there are no such specific steps, I am only following the steps mentioned in the official doc (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/authentication/auth-aad-sso) and that too is working nicely in mobile apps, messaging extension, and teams tab but not working in case of bot task module.