# Teams Task Module SSO issue

Tags: azure-active-directory, botframework, microsoft-teams

Teams SSO is working fine in Teams Tab and task module of Messaging extension but getting below error in Teams Bot task module while fetching client token

**ExtensionTabService: getAuthTokenForApp: Failed with error - Definition not found**

Using below code to open task module in teams bot with help of hero card -

[https://teams.microsoft.com/l/task/${appId}?url=${modalUrl}&height=${height}&width=${width}&title=${title}`](https://teams.microsoft.com/l/task/$%7BappId%7D?url=$%7BmodalUrl%7D&height=$%7Bheight%7D&width=$%7Bwidth%7D&title=$%7Btitle%7D%60)

The same code is also working in the Teams Bot task module in Android Mobile Application.
But getting error in browsers, desktop app of mac and windows

Comment: Are you trying to open the sso page in taskmodule? if yes you need to add bot id to the link as documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/what-are-task-modules#task-module-deep-link-syntax). try if that helps..

Comment: Yes am trying to open sso page in task module.
Tried adding bot id but getting the same error.

Comment: @Nikitha-MSFT any update on this ??

Comment: Currently SSO is available only on Teams tab. We are working on it, We don't have ETA to share when it will be available in Bot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Nikitha mentioned in comment, we have confirmed with engineering team that it is not available on Teams tab now but they have it in their backlog. No ETA for now but I will update once they have any news forit.

Thanks.

Comment: Is this still true? I am getting the same error in the same scenario