# Is SSO in a Teams task module launched by a bot supported yet

Tags: microsoft-teams

I'm trying to add SSO to an html task module as documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/authentication/auth-aad-sso?tabs=dotnet), which specifies tabs, but also says that bots are supported.  The issue is that when I call microsoftTeams.authentication.getAuthToken, I get back "App webApplicationInfo or resource not defined in manifest" (even though I've defined those in the manifest).  A quick search led me to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63485928/teams-task-module-sso-issue), which sounds similar.  This was from August 2020 though, so I'm hoping this is just me missing something, and not a case that this still isn't supported a year and a half later.  Can anyone confirm whether I should be able to auth a user with SSO from a bot-created task module (launched from an adaptive card in a 1:1 conversation).

Comment: Could you please refer this sample : https://github.com/serverless-me/msteams-bot-taskmodule-sso-54 and check if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to close the loop on this, I did figure out that yes, this does indeed work.  The instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/authentication/auth-aad-sso?tabs=dotnet) apply to task modules as well as tabs.  Calling the teams SDK microsoftTeams.authentication.getAuthToken method works as expected.  To make graph calls from the task module however, you do still need to trade the auth token in using AcquireTokenOnBehalfOf, which I accomplished by posting back to the bot api from the task module with the SSO token in the authorization header.  Once you have that token, then you can call graph APIs.

Comment: Hey Chris, I'm experiencing the same issue. Quick question - does the getAuthToken method obtain a token without requiring the user to sign in? Or are they forced to sign in despite being logged into Teams. Thanks

Comment: Another question as well, what changes did you make to the bot's webApplicationInfo property in the Teams manifest to allow for SSO to work in the task module?

Comment: 1. When you are using getAuthtoken, you are telling Teams to obtain an access token for the tab application which Teams requests from Azure AD endpoint for the signed in user. Also, the user needs to do consent if logging in for the first time if admin has not provided any consent. 2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/authentication/bot-sso-manifest